# C - Segfault when accessing member of non null pointer struct

Tags: c, memory, struct, segmentation-fault

I made a basic LinkedList in C and I have creation, addition and get working. Apart from get causes a segfault after a seemingly random amount of get calls (Fails on 96th call, the list has 94 elements in it) accessing the next pointer on the current node causes a segfault.

This line causes the segfault `while(cur->next != null && i < index)` I have checked and cur is not returning a null memory address before the segfault occurs. It also crashes on the second loop of the call that crashes it (Second printf only outputs 0).
This is the entire get function

```
void *linkedList_get(LinkedList list, int index)
{
    Node *cur = list.head;
    int i = 0;
    if(index != 0)
    {
        while(cur->next != null && i < index)
        {
            cur = cur->next;
            printf("I %i\n", i);
            printf("%i\n", cur);
            i++;
        }
    }
    if(index == i)
        return cur->data;
    return null;
}
```

This is the Node struct

```
typedef struct
{
    void *data;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *prev;
} Node;
```

This is the entire code if needed http://pastebin.com/hpWA8tb8 (Note this is my first C program, so it's probably a bit sloppy and I don't free any memory)

Comment: Probably not the source of your bug, but you should modify your function above to check to make sure list.head isn't NULL before dereferencing cur->next.

Comment: If you run this program under the debugger, what does the call stack look like when the segfault occurs?

Comment: I'm using Code::Blocks with Mingw32 and for some reason the debugger refuses to work, which has made debugging the numerous segfaults I've caused as a beginner C programmer very hard to debug haha.

Comment: I've never bothered with C++, but I am primarily a Java programmer so OOP is my background. Why not typedef it? The only difference I know of is that I have to do struct structname varname instead of structname varname which seems better to me.

Answer (score 1):

`createEmptyNode` does not actually return `n`.  This means the node pointers in use in the linked list are actually bogus (and pointing off anywhere in memory).  Same for many of your other create functions.

You should compile with warnings enabled, which would probably have caught this.  (Using `-Wall` on GCC, for example).

In general, if you have any memory errors in a C program, you can't reason perfectly about the behaviour of it after that error is triggered.  So I won't claim that fixing this will make it work. ;-)  There's also an error where you set the data in a node, assigning the pointer instead of the pointer's content (for which you should use something like `memmove`, passing the content's size explicitly).

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I forgot return values for every one of those functions. It still crashes at the same point though.

Comment: would you also recommend using valgrind?

Comment: I've never used valgrind, though I've read in lots of places that I should be!  I sometimes run the code in MSVC which can detect some memory errors (possibly similar to valgrind).

Comment: If you compile with all warnings enabled, are there any other warning messages you haven't resolved yet?

Comment: There's 11 warnings, so far I've been ignoring them because they don't seem to have been affecting anything and I don't really know what they mean. Warnings http://i.imgur.com/3bcrf.png the error is because I have to have a compilation error for warnings to show up for some reason.

Comment: You might want to edit the question to link to the latest source, so the line numbers match up. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Edmund likely found the answer.  But I also caught this:

This is dangerously wrong, especially on 64-bit OS and compiles were sizeof pointer is larger than sizeof(int).

```
Node *n = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
```

It should read:

```
Node *n = malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

Answer (score 1):

As Edmund said, there may be many errors in this program,

I object to this part:

```
next->data = malloc(sizeof(data));
next->data = data;
```

It allocates some memory to next->data, then IMMEDIATELY erases that pointer, and puts in a different value.   Memory is certainly leaked, and other consequences may result.

Comment: I still haven't entirely gotten manual memory management down, but I do see how that makes no sense so I've remove the malloc call.

Comment: data is also of type void * -- you should be passing the size of data into linkedList_add from getFilesInDir, etc.