# Code compiles but gives segmentationfault when run with game board

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

### Question

My ultimate goal is to open a game board for a game like this:  http://www.rci-jeux.com/jeux/labychiffres/laby.swf and then play it as a university assignment (I am abroad and can't always follow everything the lecturer says).

My problem is I think in `pile.c` - the third block of code below. I have identified that with gdb (which I am very inexperienced with): (I have removed comments from the code so the line number is incorrect - but it still says `DEBUGGING PROBLEM` on the line it refers to).

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400ee6 in afficher_pile (pile=...) at pile.c:48
48            afficher(P_elt->valeur);//########DEBUGGING PROBLEM
```

This looks to me like the very simple `afficher` (print) function is  referring to something it shouldn't be, but I have basically (as the instructor suggested) edited some simple string manipulation function he provided us with, where the type or structure was a character and a pointer to the next one, and the end of the chain had(if I understood correctly) a `NULL` pointer.

I am very new to programming, but we have had quite extensive guidance on the structures, so they should be appropriate and correct (as should the `pile.c` functions).

### What I have tried

Initially I thought I was passing the `valeur` part of the element incorrectly, so I tried changing `afficher(P_elt->valeur);` in various ways:

`afficher(P_elt.valeur);`

`afficher(*P_elt.valeur);`

`afficher(&P_elt.valeur);`

These three do not compile saying `member valeur in something not a struct or union`

`afficher(&P_elt->valeur);` compilation error: `expected ‘POSITION’ but argument is of type ‘struct POSITION *`

`afficher(*P_elt->valeur);` compilation error: `invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘POSITION’)`

I have looked for questions like this: [C - Segfault when accessing member of non null pointer struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561160/c-segfault-when-accessing-member-of-non-null-pointer-struct)

[C segmentation fault when trying to implement LinkedList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851057/c-segmentation-fault-when-trying-to-implement-linkedlist) (I was hopeful about this one but I don't think it is my error, I am sure that my code does initialise the structure with a NULL pointer.)

Basically I haven't found anything else to try, and would like to make more progress before the final opportunity to look at things with the lecturer.

### Code below

1.`proj.h` Header file (N.B. this contains prototypes for some functions I haven't written yet.)

2.`proj.c` Will be main file, not much progress yet.

3.`pile.c` Contains the code highlighted by gdb as causing the segmentation fault, also functions for manipulating the list of positions that eventually the player and a solver will use to solve the game.

4.`allocate_plat.c` This reads a game file (the program would previously load and display the grid from the game file.) This might be where the problem is as the PILE structure is initialised here with values from the game board.

5.`makefile` Probably not necessary but turned out to contain a problem previously.

6.`plateau1.txt` This seems to copy into a text editor correctly (from the preview at least - there should be no trailing whitespace (though I don't know if that matters)).

1.`proj.h`

```
#pragma once

typedef struct position_st{
    int indl;//indice of ligne
    int indc;//indice of colonne
    }POSITION;

typedef struct element_st{
    POSITION valeur;
    struct element_st *P_suivant;
    }ELEMENT;

typedef struct pile_st{
    ELEMENT * P_sommet;
    }PILE;

//##########PLATEAU STRUCTURE DEFINITION##############
typedef struct plat_st{
//########## INFORMATION INCLUDED IN AND READ FROM THE GAME FILE
    int nl;//number of lignes in grille
    int nc;//number of colonnes in grille
    POSITION dep;//position du depart: dep.indl and dep.indc
    POSITION arr;//position d'arrive: arr.indl and arr.indc
    int longdem;//longueur demandee
    int sumdem;//totale demandee
    int ** grille;//Playing grid done by analogy with matrix
//#######INFORMATION TO DO WITH THE CURRENT GAME ########
    int longcur;//longueur courant
    int sumcur;//totale courant
    PILE chemin;//The path
    }PLATEAU;


//########## FUNCTION PROTOTYPES and source files ###############
//allocate_plat.c allocate_plat.c allocate_plat.c allocate_plat.c 
//allouer allocates the variables for the game
int allouer(PLATEAU *, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int);
//lire reads a game from a file
int lire(char *, PLATEAU *);
//affiche prints grille
void affiche_grille(PLATEAU);

//pile.c pile.c pile.c pile.c pile.c pile.c pile.c pile.c pile.c 
//FONCTIONS DE PILE ETC
int afficher (POSITION); prints position
ELEMENT* nouvel_element (POSITION);
void initialiser_pile(PILE *);
int est_vide (PILE);
int afficher_pile (PILE);
int longueur_pile (PILE);
ELEMENT* empiler(PILE *, ELEMENT *);
ELEMENT* depiler (PILE *);
POSITION lire_sommet (PILE *);

//grille.c grille.c grille.c grille.c grille.c grille.c grille.c 
// GRILLE.C FONCTIONS DE GESTION DE LA GRILLE
int lire_valeur_a(PLATEAU *,POSITION *);
int lire_passage_a(POSITION);
int lire_direction_a(POSITION);
int ecrire_passage_a(POSITION);
int ecrire_direction_a(POSITION);
```

2.`proj.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "proj.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int choix, choix2, succes;
    PLATEAU jeu;
    ELEMENT *P_elt;//////////// ELEMENT HERE *P_elt

    if (argc == 1){
        printf("Erreur : argument manquant !\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char *nom_fichier = argv[1];
    succes=lire(nom_fichier, &jeu);

    if (!succes){
        printf("Erreur lors de la lecture du fichier !\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    afficher_pile(jeu.chemin);

    if (est_vide(jeu.chemin) == 0){
        printf("Chemin vide\n");
    }
    printf("%d. this is 0 if chemin not empty",est_vide(jeu.chemin));
    affiche_grille(jeu);
    afficher_pile(jeu.chemin);
    if(!est_vide(jeu.chemin)) afficher(lire_sommet(&jeu.chemin));
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

3.`pile.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "proj.h"

////////// AFFICHER POSITION ////////////////////////////
int afficher(POSITION v){
    printf("\t%d %d", v.indl,v.indc);
}

///////// NOUVEL_ELEMENT /////////////////////////////
ELEMENT *nouvel_element (POSITION nouvelle_valeur){
    ELEMENT *P_elt;
    P_elt =(ELEMENT*) malloc(sizeof(ELEMENT));

    if(P_elt ) {
        P_elt->valeur= nouvelle_valeur;
        P_elt->P_suivant=NULL;
    }
    return P_elt;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void initialiser_pile(PILE *P_pile){
    P_pile->P_sommet=NULL;
}

////////////EST VIDE /////////////////////////////////////////
int est_vide (PILE pile){
   return pile.P_sommet == NULL;//i.e. true (non-zero) if P_sommet is NULL
}

////////// AFFICHER PILE PRINT PATH //////////////////
int afficher_pile (PILE pile){
   ELEMENT *P_elt; 
   int l=0;
   for(P_elt= pile.P_sommet ; P_elt!=NULL ; P_elt=P_elt->P_suivant, l++ )
      afficher(P_elt->valeur);//######## DEBUGGING PROBLEM #################
   return l;
}

/////////// LENGTH OF PATH //////////////////////////
int longueur_pile (PILE pile){
   ELEMENT *P_elt; 
   int l=0;
   for(P_elt= pile.P_sommet ; P_elt!=NULL ; P_elt=P_elt->P_suivant )
      l++;

   return l;
}

///////////EMPILER ADD ELEMENT TO PATH //////////////
ELEMENT* empiler(PILE *P_pile, ELEMENT *P_elt_ajoute){
   P_elt_ajoute ->P_suivant = P_pile->P_sommet; /*on chaine P_elt_ajoute a la suite */
   P_pile->P_sommet = P_elt_ajoute;             /*on chaine  la sommet a P_elt_ajoute */

   return P_elt_ajoute;
}
/////////DEPILER REMOVE ELEMENT FROM PATH///////////
ELEMENT* depiler (PILE *P_pile){
   ELEMENT *P_elt_supprime;
   /* Si la pile est vide */
   if (est_vide(*P_pile))
      return NULL;
   /* Si la pile n'est pas vide */
   P_elt_supprime=P_pile->P_sommet ;
   P_pile->P_sommet = P_elt_supprime->P_suivant; /*on chaine la sommet a la suite */
   P_elt_supprime->P_suivant=NULL;   /* on supprime le chainage de P_elt_supprime */

   return P_elt_supprime;
}
//*
/////////////// LIRE SOMMET ////////////////////////
POSITION lire_sommet (PILE *P_pile){
    ELEMENT *P_elt; 
//      if (est_vide(*P_pile)) 
//  return NULL;      //sortie fonction
    for(P_elt = P_pile->P_sommet; P_elt->P_suivant != NULL; P_elt = P_elt->P_suivant);
   return P_elt->valeur;
}
```

4.`allocate_plat.c` N.B. contains some repetitive fscanfs in the middle which I am quite sure work.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "proj.h"

int allouer(PLATEAU *PLAT, int nl, int nc, int ldep, int cdep, int larr, int carr, int longdem, int sumdem){
    int i,succes;
    PLAT->grille = (int**)calloc(nl,sizeof(int*));
    PLAT->nl = nl;
    PLAT->nc = nc;
    PLAT->longdem = longdem;
    PLAT->sumdem = sumdem;
    PLAT->dep.indl = ldep;
    PLAT->dep.indc = cdep;
    PLAT->arr.indl = larr;
    PLAT->arr.indc = carr;
    succes = (PLAT->grille != NULL);
    for (i=0; succes && i<nl;i++){
    PLAT->grille[i]=(int*)calloc(nc,sizeof(int));
    succes = (PLAT->grille[i] != NULL);
    }
    return succes;
}
int lire(char *nom_fichier, PLATEAU *PLAT){
    int i,j,succes, c;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen(nom_fichier, "rt");
    if(fp==NULL) {
        printf("Erreur d'ouverture du fichier\n");
        return 0;
    }
    c = fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&PLAT->nl,&PLAT->nc);//Read first line
    if( c != 2){
        printf("Erreur de format de fichier\n");
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }
    c = fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&i,&j);//Read second line
    PLAT->dep.indl=i-1;
    PLAT->dep.indc=j-1;
    if( c != 2){
        printf("Erreur de format de fichier\n");
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }
    c = fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&i,&j);//Read third line
    PLAT->arr.indl=i-1;
    PLAT->arr.indc=j-1;
    if( c != 2){
        printf("Erreur de format de fichier\n");
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }
    c = fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&PLAT->longdem,&PLAT->sumdem);//Read fourth line
    if( c != 2){
        printf("Erreur de format de fichier\n");
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }

    if( c != 2){
        printf("Erreur de format de fichier\n");
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }
//ALLOCATE THE FILE TO THE STRUCT
    succes = allouer(PLAT, PLAT->nl, PLAT->nc, PLAT->dep.indl, PLAT->dep.indc, PLAT->arr.indl, PLAT->arr.indc, PLAT->longdem, PLAT->sumdem );
    if(succes==0) {
        printf("Erreur d'allocation\n");
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }
    for(i=0; i< PLAT->nl; i++){
        for(j=0; j<PLAT->nc; j++){
            c=fscanf(fp, "%d", &PLAT->grille[i][j]);
            if(c != 1){
                printf("Erreur de format de fichier\n");
                fclose(fp);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    ELEMENT *P_sommet = nouvel_element(PLAT->dep);
    if (P_sommet==NULL){
        printf("Erreur d'allocation\n");
        return 0;
    }
    empiler (&PLAT->chemin,P_sommet);
    PLAT->longcur=1;
    PLAT->sumcur=PLAT->grille[PLAT->dep.indl][PLAT->dep.indc];
    //ABOVE LINE INITIALISES THESE THINGS WHEN THE FILE IS READ
    return 1;
}
//AFFICHE - PRINT GRILL ONLY
void affiche_grille(PLATEAU jeu){
    int i,j;
    printf("\nEtat du jeu\n");
    for(i=0; i < jeu.nl; i++){
        for(j=0; j < jeu.nc; j++){
            if (jeu.dep.indl == i  && jeu.dep.indc == j){
                printf("D %d\t", jeu.grille[i][j]);
            }
            else if (jeu.arr.indl == i && jeu.arr.indc == j){
                printf("%d A\t", jeu.grille[i][j]);
            }
            else printf("%d\t",jeu.grille[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");//Final new line
}
```

5.`makefile`

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -I . #-Wall
DEPS = proj.h
OBJ = proj.o allocate_plat.o pile.o grille.o

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -g -c -o $@ $<

proj: $(OBJ)
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -g -o $@ $^
```

6.Example game file `plateau1.txt`, first line is #rows and columns, 2nd and 3rd starting and finishing coordinates, 4th is path length required and sum of grid values required and the last 4 lines are the grid.

```
4 4
1 1
4 4
11 96
10 13 2 5
3 15 9 4
8 6 11 14
7 12 1 16
```

Comment: You have lots of uninitialized pointers. You never call `initialiser_pile`, for instance.

Comment: In `main()`, you declare `ELEMENT *P_elt`, but never assign it. But that's OK, because you never use it, either.

Comment: Calling `initialiser_pile` just before `empiler` at the end of `lire` in `allocate_plat` helps thanks. No  longer a segmentation fault.

Comment: In your loop last element is never null unless, by random chance, as you never initialize it. `P_elt != NULL` is (always) true. As a result the loop continues beyond range of elements and access some random address causing segfault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have lots of uninitialized pointers. You never call `initialiser_pile`, for instance.
                    – Barmar

Calling `initialiser_pile` just before `empiler` at the end of `lire` in `allocate_plat` helps thanks. No  longer a segmentation fault.
                    – Luskentyrian